# Bash script to tar.gz file by day

Tags: linux, bash

I have few catalogues in my linux directory , the files name is logs-YYMMDD

```
/logs-140617
/logs-140616
/logs-140615
```

Can somebody tell me how to write bash script to repeat every day and pack file by date -1 day (today bash script would create archive of logs-140616 and delete unpacked file ?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 1):

use logrotate for that purpose, that's what it is for.
For periodically executing stuff, a cron job is the way to do that.
logrotate already gets executed by cron, on a daily base. Therefore, when using logrotate, there would be not need to fiddle with the daily-execution aspect of your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you tell me how to configure logrotate to take only 1 file with previous date  ?

Comment: what could I possibly repeat here what hasn't been written already in its manual page?  the  "rotate" directive can take an argument. You'd use logrotate to create those archived log files, from files matching locations and pattern you specify. You control number to keep and frequency of generation of those archives.